# How can I color every other row, but skip rows marked X?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I color every other row but skip any row where `Column A = X`?

Whats wrong is it colors over my sub heading rows. I am trying to get it to skip the heading rows which is marked by an invisible `X` in Column `A`.

Can it skip the sub headings and the row below the sub heading row be white? Kind of like its starting over again.

This is the code I have that colors rows white then gray to the end for the entire range:

```
Sub Format()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Form")

sht2.Activate
sht2.Unprotect

Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim WholeRng As Range

With sht2
    Set rng = Cells

    LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    LastCol = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    WholeRng.Select

    With WholeRng
        With .Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range(Cells(4, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End With

    Dim b As Boolean
    For Each rng In WholeRng.Rows
        If Not rng.Hidden Then
            If b Then rng.Interior.Color = Black
            b = Not b
        End If
    Next
End With

Set rng = Nothing
Set WholeRng = Nothing
Set sht2 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a couple of comments - your `LastRow`, `LastCol` variable could hold nothing if the sheet is blank and the `WholeRng` will throw an error as a result.  The `WholeRng.Select` line isn't needed - you'll colour the interior without it being selected.  You might also want to `resize` your `WholeRng` to add borders rather than use the `LastRow`, `LastCol` on the `ActiveSheet` (you haven't qualified the sheet name with your range references).

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? Just thinking: if you use conditional formatting, based on a formula, and you use as a formula condition : `=Offset(here,1-Column,0) == "x"` => this would look for every cell, go `1-Column` to the right (or `Column - 1` to the left, ending up in column `A`), and then check if the value equals `"x"`. Just one problem: does anybody know how to fill in the first argument of `Offset()` formula? How to say : "Offset from this cell onwards"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expand your current [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx), using the [and operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251591.aspx).

Example:

```
Dim b As Boolean
For Each rng In WholeRng.Rows
    If Not rng.Hidden Then
        ' UPDATED LINE BELOW.
        If b And sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 1) <> "x" Then rng.Interior.Color = Black
        b = Not b
    End If
Next
```

The code extracts the current row number from the `rng` object.  It uses that to peek at the contents of column a.

An alternative approach is to use Excel's built-in [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB).  This is probably the easier method.